# Should I be worried about my background check?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I was recently accepted for a job, and now I have to go through a screening process. I did not include a job that I'd left after 5 weeks on my CV, as I did not feel it was relevant and did not want to talk about it in the interview. (the job was not as it was advertised, the colleagues were toxic and they did not follow their own policies.)

I left this job just over a month ago and am worried it will come up on my background check, I am extremely worried as I want this job so much and I don't want my previous job to sabotage my chances.

Comment: A similar question has been answered here - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/24561/113352

Does it help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your average background check is there to look into criminal records, arrests or court judgements against you that you have not mentioned in interview. While they might pick up on jobs you worked at for 5-week periods, the only thing that might be of concern to your average employer for an average job would be more than one such job where you bailed after such a short amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be worried about my background check?

Will it help you? No.

Can you change anything? You don't have to. If anybody asks you about this, just explain how you explain it to us. It's okay to leave a toxic environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, none of us can answer this question, because the motivations for doing background checks vary widely among employers. As a result of that variation, interpretation of the results also varies widely. Some employers will care about things that others don't even look at.

That said, it's somewhat common for candidates to leave jobs off their resume for various reasons. Some people with really long resumes will prune jobs just to keep the resume at a reasonable size. Other times, when a job isn't relevant to the specific opportunity at hand, you can leave it off for that reason. Most employers understand that, and many will be totally okay with a job being left off.

Employers don't like being lied to, but leaving a job off your resume doesn't automatically count as a "lie" in every case. Some employers **will** want to know about every position you've ever held, but the good news is that those employers will make their needs known - they will tell you to list *every single job* at some point in the hiring process. If you weren't explicitly asked to give details on every single job you've ever held, leaving a job off your resume is likely not an issue.